# In netcoreapp3.0 console application, myprogram.exe (with extension exe) is generated by default. What is it?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I have the following simple project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
 </Project>
```

**In netcoreapp3.0:**

When run 'dotnet build', I find  a file myprogram.dll is generated with size 5k plus myprogram.exe is generated with size 239k

**In netcoreapp2.2:**

The myprogram.exe isn't generated.

I can run the program :

```
    dotnet myprogram.dll
```

Or

```
    myprogram.exe //it need .netcore be installed.
```

Why are the the two files: myprogram.exe and myprogram.dll is generated in netcoreapp3.0, but in netcoreapp2.2 only myprogram.dll is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/

> NET Core applications are now built with executables. This is new for applications that use a globally installed version of .NET Core. Until now, only self-contained applications had executables. You can see executables produced in the following examples.
>
> You can expect the same things with these executables as you would other native executables, such as:
>
> - You can double click on the executable.
> - You can launch the application from a command prompt without using the dotnet tool, using myconsole.exe, on Windows, and ./myconsole, on Linux and macOS, as you can see in the following examples.

So, it is just a more convenient way to use the program. You don't need to use a command line such as `dotnet myapp.dll` to start the application. You can run the exe.

Comment: It's a promising feature.